# display enum inside radio buttons, winforms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, enums, radio-button

I have enum datatype

```
public enum UserChoices { Basic = 0, Lite = 1, Standard = 2 };
```

How can I use this enum property inside winforms radio button choices?

Comment: Duplicated - http://stackoverflow.com/a/9283542/1426106 in addition, there are many examples out there on google.

Comment: refer to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2476829/winforms-bind-enum-to-radio-buttons

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use below code to get the name and values in an Array.

```
string[] names = Enum.GetNames(typeof(MyEnum));
MyEnum[] values = (MyEnum[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(MyEnum));
```

Now

```
for( int i = 0; i < names.Length; i++ )
{
    //Add this item to radio button list
    //names[i] will be going to text
    //values[i] will be going to value
}
```

Queries welcomed!